# symfony2 form date widget year validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, date

I'm using this configuration for my form date widget:

```
$builder->add('birthdate', DateType::class, array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'html5' => false,
    'format' => $dateFormat,
    'attr' => array(
        'data-mask' => $this->i18n->getDataMaskFromDateFormat($dateFormat)
    ),
    'label' => $dateFormat
));
```

However, dates like 1234-05-06 are valid. Is there a way to specify the validation of the year range, so that only dates between a specific range are valid?

Best Christian

### Update

#### Validation File

path FooBundle\Resources\config\validation\Foo\Bar.yml

```
FooBundle\Model\Foo\Bar\Bar:
    constraints:
        - Propel\PropelBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueObject:
            fields:  email
            message: messages.email_exists
    properties:
        name:
            - NotNull:
                message : messages.null
        email:
            - NotNull:
                message : messages.null
            - Email:
                message : messages.invalid_email
        plainPassword:
            - NotBlank:
                message : messages.null
        birthdate:
            - NotBlank:
                message : messages.null
            - Date:
                message: messages.invalid_date
            - GreaterThan: -100 years
```

The file is loaded correctly, because the other constraints are validating successfully the model. The only problem is, that GreaterThan doesn't work.

I think, it doesn't work, because symfony is checking wheather the value is an instance of \DateTime, which is (but I'm not quite sure) wrong for strings like "1987-09-01". But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Is this for all cases ? You can use Assert validation directly into concerned entity : http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-date-support-for-validator-constraints

Comment: Or that : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#years but you have to set "widget" to "choice"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added this to my validation: "- LessThan: -100 years". But now all dates are invalid (Dieser Wert sollte kleiner als "-100 years" sein.) for input "1987-09-01" ...

Comment: You want that user select date like now - 100 years < selected date ? Currently you have defined that selected data has to be like that :  selected date < now - 100 years (=1916) ! Define `Assert\GreaterThan("- 100 years")`

Answer (score 0):

So you can use Validator Constraint (http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-date-support-for-validator-constraints) :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class YourEntity
{
    /**
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual("-100 years")
     */
    protected $date;
}
```

XML :

```
<!-- src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<constraint-mapping xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping/constraint-mapping-1.0.xsd">

    <class name="AppBundle\Entity\YourEntity">
        <property name="date">
            <constraint name="GreaterThanOrEqual">-100 years</constraint>
        </property>
    </class>
</constraint-mapping>
```

YML :

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
AppBundle\Entity\YourEntity:
    properties:
        date:
            - GreaterThanOrEqual: -100 years
```

Comment: Hm...but invalid dates like 1655-09-01 are still valid with this. The "return $value1 > $value2;" from the compareValues method gives me a "1655-09-01 > -100 years". I have to say, that I do not use validation constraints in my model classes. Instead of this I use validation.yml files, but that should be the same.

Comment: My bad, I think it is because I let a blank space before "100". Could you try ?

Comment: While I second the suggestion about validation, I should add that you can also add a "min" attribute to your widget (and, of course, also a "max" one), to enhance user experience

Comment: Delphine, this doesnt works :/ I think he is comparing the strings, not the actual dates. Is there anything else, I have to consider?

Comment: Massimiliano, thank you, but how to use dates with min, max range? Docs says, that they are only allow integers.

Comment: Heum.. Could you update your question with your validation.yml (path and file content) + your stack trace ?

Comment: I updated the question and posted the validation config. Which strack trace do you mean?

Comment: In Symfony console log, just to see where check is done but whatever. I'm perplexe. Maybe it is because it is not a DateTime but just a date "1987-09-01" instead of "1987-09-01 00:00:00". Your attribute, in your entity, is defined as datetime or date ?

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up with building my own Validator:

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    $date = new \DateTime($value);
    $today = new \DateTime('today');
    $past = new \DateTime('-100 years');

    if ($date < $past || $date > $today) {
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)->addViolation();
    }
}
```